# Racket GUI, drawing text vertically, issues with "angle" argument

Tags: user-interface, text, racket, angle

I'm using the Racket GUI to write text in the window of my program.
Until now I only needed to draw text horizontally. But now **I would** also **want to write text vertically**. I saw in the documentation we can give an **"angle" argument** when we send the message "draw-text" to the drawing context.

Here's my little function to draw text :

```
(define (draw-text text fontsize x y color [rotate-angle 0.0]) 
  (when (string? color) 
    (set! color (send the-color-database find-color color)))
  (send bitmap-dc set-font (make-object font% fontsize 'default))
  (send bitmap-dc set-text-foreground color)
  (send bitmap-dc draw-text text x y [angle rotate-angle])
  (update-callback))
```

But when I call the "draw-text" procedure with example given an angle of 90° (so that the text would be vertically) it doesn't change anything.
It's just displayed as before, horizontally.

Does someone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the example, but did you remember to convert the 90 degrees into radians? The convention is that 360 degrees is the same as 2pi radians. Or dividing by 360, we get that 1 degree is 2pi/360 radians.

Multiplying by 90, the result is that 90 degrees is 90*2*pi/360 = 180pi/260 = pi/2 ~ 1.5707963267948966. That is, to rotate the text 90 degrees, use 1.5707963267948966 as the rotate-angle.

Also `(send bitmap-dc draw-text text x y [angle rotate-angle])`
should be

```
(send bitmap-dc draw-text text x y combine? offset? angle])
```

For example:

```
(send bitmap-dc draw-text "A text" 100 100 #t 0 1.570])
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was I did not used the "combine?" and "offset" arguments, I thought they were optional. Now it works.

Comment: They are optional, but if there are more optional arguments, you need to all arguments before the one you need.. For example, suppose foo has optional arguments x and y written as `(foo [x y])`. Now in `(foo 3)` is 3 an x or an y? Here 3 is an x value. So if y=3 I need to write `(foo 3 4)`.

Comment: Also note that racket/math has a built-in `degrees->radians` function.